# How can I grab the element by matching text in its attribute in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code

```
<a title="Next Page - Results 1 to 60 " href="bla bla" class="smallfont" rel="next">&gt;</a>
```

I want to grab the `a` element and get the href .

how can I match the `title` attribute with `Next Page`

I want to partially match the text in title attribute of the `a` element.

There are many `a` tags on the page similar to it but only difference is that the `title` attribute contains `"Next Page` or the text is `>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use Regex for accomplishing what you want.

First take the entire markup as a string and make a `BeautifulSoup` object with it.

Then use the `.findAll` method of the `BeautifulSoup` object as follows

```
import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup('<a title="Next Page - Results 1 to 60 " href="bla bla" class="smallfont" rel="next">&gt;</a>')

elements = soup.findAll('a', {'title':re.compile('Next Page.')}) 
# get all 'a' elements with 'title' attribute as 'Next Page something' into a list

for e in elements:
    if str(e.string) == '>' or e.string == '&gt;': # check if string inside 'a' tag is '>'
        print e['href']
```

Comment: Hope you know what `'Next Page.'` means in Regex, if not I can clarify.